# Keras with Tensorflow Backend - Import Error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda, keras, gpu

I have just installed tensorflow-gpu with python3. When I tried it, I got the error below.

Code:

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Error:

```
/logiciels/Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/projets/iris/PROJETS/WEIR/python_env/inherited/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/projets/iris/PROJETS/WEIR/python_env/inherited/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/projets/iris/PROJETS/WEIR/python_env/inherited/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/projets/iris/PROJETS/WEIR/python_env/inherited/python3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/projets/iris/PROJETS/WEIR/python_env/inherited/python3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)  ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you verify your installation of tensorflow and keras?

Comment: Make sure CUDA 9.0 is correctly installed on your machine. then set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the right path (ex: `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64`)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm working at a platform that's not under my control, so I use virtual environment to make my installations, I'll try to check CUDA 9.0

Comment: In fact, since I'm running programs in the server of my lab, I'm not allowed to install CUDA, instead, I'll use docker instances provided with keras and tensorflow then create virtual environments from the system packages, now, there is no need to install tensorflow-gpu. Thanks for your responses. I keep these remarques for future installations in my own machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It seems your Tensorflow version has been compiled for CUDA 9.0. Make sure you have this version of CUDA properly installed and referenced, or compile Tensorflow yourself to suit your environment ([install doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)).